# Symbol#to_proc with custom methods

Tags: ruby

I like how in Ruby you can pass methods as blocks like so using `Symbol#to_proc`:

```
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0].map(&:to_i)
#=> [1, 2, 3]
```

I can also define my own lambda, `times_two`, and pass it as a block as well:

```
times_two = ->(x) {x * 2}

[1, 2, 3].map(&times_two)
#=> [2, 4, 6]
```

Though I seemingly *cannot* pass `times_two` as a symbol:

```
[1, 2, 3].map(&:times_two)
#=> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

However when I try to do the same with a method I get an error:

```
def times_three(x)
  x * 3
end

[1, 2, 3].map(&times_three)
#=> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

[1, 2, 3].map(&:times_three)
#=> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

I'm guessing I can't do this because `times_three` is a method, not a Proc.

So how can you define custom methods so that they can be used in the `Symbol#to_proc` fashion like `to_i` in the first example above?

For example, how can I do this?

```
[1, 2, 3].map(&:times_three)
#=> [3, 6, 9]
```

EDIT: 
I watched the video posted below and apparently you can get close to Symbol#to_proc using the `method` method:

```
def times_three(x)
  x * 3
end

t_three = method(:times_three)
[1, 2, 3].map(&t_three)
#=> [3, 6, 9]
```

However, it's not quite Symbol#to_proc:

```
[1, 2, 3].map(&:t_three)
#=> NoMethodError: undefined method `t_three' for 1:FixNum
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class Integer
  def times_three
    return self * 3
  end
end
```

Now, because times_three is now a method of the Integer class, you can do symbol to proc...

```
[1, 2, 3].map(&:times_three)
```

If you want to access a method that isn't part of the object's class but acts on an object, you need to pass the object as an argument to the method...

```
def times_three(x)
  x * 3
end

[1, 2, 3].map{|i| times_three(i) }
```

the `symbol to proc` needs to use the object as a receiver.

```
[1, 2, 3].map(&:some_action)
```

is equivalent to

```
[1, 2, 3].map{|i| i.some_action}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this clear explanation, Steve. Now that I know how to do this, is it acceptable practice to monkey patch core classes with methods like these in order to clean up complex or repetitive blocks?

Comment: Well, yes, provided the intention is clear and there's a benefit, it's definitely ok to monkey patch.

I had a rails application this week where mandatory input fields had an asterisk in the labels, e.g. `'First Name *'` and `'City *'` and the business suddenly wanted all the asterisks to be a red font color.  I could've written a helper method like `red_asterisk('First Name *')` but it was easier to monkey patch the String class `'First Name *'.red_asterisk` and then just do a global find/replace on `*'` so it became `*'.red_asterisk`

Comment: Steve, as you well know, `return` is not needed. `self` is, however. I assume `self` must be explicit for methods such such as `*`, `%`  which are invoiked with syntactic sugar. Do you or anyone else know if that is true?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I assume it is, because I assume the syntactic sugar isn't used by the parser, just by us simple coders. :)  in my conceptual model `*` is likely interpreted as `self.*(arg)` or more likely `self.send(:*, arg)` so you'd need `def *; result =0; arg.times{result += self};result;end` If the output is conditional on the receiver  (3*5 is not the same as 7*5), you need to use `self`. If you want to have output unconditioned, say, `3*5 => "I dunno"; 7*5 => "I dunno"` then you skip `self`.  Any newbies reading this, don't try this at home!  Not good to monkey patch `*`, `%`, `+`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to define `times_three` on `Integer` or `Numeric`.

Symbol to Proc explained by Peter Cooper: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aISNtCAZlMg

Comment: Instead of linking to random reference, you should write short explanation/copy it here and give the link as source for your anwser.

Comment: Thanks for the video. However it doesn't show why I would have to define ```times_three``` on ```Integer``` or ```Numeric```. It shows how ```to_proc``` is implemented on a class before Ruby adopted Symbol#to_proc, though the video doesn't show how you can define your own methods this way.

Comment: @garythegoat: It does show how `Symbol#to_proc` is implemented, namely that it calls the method on the first argument of the block, passing the other arguments of the block as arguments of the method call. In your case, the first argument of the block is `1` (in the first iteration), and there are no other arguments, so `Symbol#to_proc` calls `1.times_three`, ergo, `times_three` needs to be defined in one of `1`'s classes, i.e. `Fixnum`, `Integer`, `Numeric`, `Object`, `Kernel`, or `BasicObject`. Unfortunately, [the docs are crap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc), …

Comment: … and [the source code of `Symbol#to_proc` in YARV](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/string.c#L7224-7251) isn't of much help either. Thankfully, Rubinius never disappoints, the sources are much more readable, in fact, the meat of it is basically just one line: [`proc do |*args, &b| args.shift.send(self, *args, &b) end`](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/kernel/common/symbol.rb#L118).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
[1, 2, 3].map &method(:t_three)
```

Here is an excellent [resource](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p4U2_acQ9ks) to learn more about this technique.