# Passing custom method from custom class to .map

Tags: ruby, proc

I'm working on an exercise for exercism.io - the instructions are long and not relevant to this question but you can find my full solution [here](http://exercism.io/submissions/6194c0f99791401a8a4efafe84733492).

Basically I have a `Robot` class and 3 private methods:

```
  def rand_letters
    ('A'..'Z').to_a[rand(26)]
  end

  def rand_numbers
    (0..9).to_a[rand(10)]
  end
```

What I'm trying to do is pass these to another private method like so:

```
  def set_name
    @name = ((1..2).map(&:rand_letters) + (3..5).map(&:rand_numbers)).join
  end
```

When I do this I get the error:`undefined method 'rand_letters' for 1:Fixnum`. After looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388368/symbolto-proc-with-custom-methods) I thought that maybe the problem was that my class didn't have a to_proc method. Unfortunately I'm not sure how to correct this. I tried making my class inherit from `Proc` but I'm stuck on how to override `to_proc`. Any help pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Two questions: Is this part of the requirement to use the short syntax (`.map(&:method)`) and if yes - are you allowed to monkey patch the `Fixnum` and `String` classes?

Comment: Also what do you expect to be the result - do you want a random letter/digit to be mapped to each element in the range?

Comment: No it's not part of the requirement just someone mentioned it in the comments (you can see them on the link to the full solution) and they had suggested map(&:method)

Comment: I'm expecting two random letters and three digits- eg: BX500  - on the link to exercism.io there's links to previous iterations of my solution. If you want, you might get a better idea of what's happening by glancing through the critique I received there.

Comment: You can use `(1..2).map { rand_letters }` instead. You can also do it the short way, but this will require monkey patching to `Fixnum`/`String`. However, if you find another way please do share the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: you can use `array.sample` instead of `array[rand(x)]` to get a random element from an array.

Furthermore, you can replace `(1..n).map` by `n.times.map`:

```
(2.times.map { rand_letters } + 3.times.map { rand_numbers }).join
```

But using `map` feels counter intuitive to me. Wouldn't it be much easier if we could simply grab 3 random letters?

This can be achieved by returning an [`Enumerator`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerator.html) instead of a single value. The plural naming already suggest that the `rand_` methods are supposed to return multiple values:

```
def rand_letters
  return enum_for(__method__) unless block_given?
  loop { yield ('A'..'Z').to_a.sample }
end

def rand_numbers
  return enum_for(__method__) unless block_given?
  loop { yield (0..9).to_a.sample }
end
```

This allows us to call [`Enumerable#take`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-take):

```
(rand_letters.take(2) + rand_numbers.take(3)).join
#=> "ZJ010"
```

Or using the `[...]` literal:

```
[rand_letters.take(2), rand_numbers.take(3)].join
```

Comment: I actually did end up using `Array#sample` so thank you for mentioning it. And thanks also for the wonderfully detailed explanation. It's really made me think!

Comment: @SoSimple note that `sample(n)` returns `n` *unique* elements, i.e. you're excluding duplicate elements in your [current code](http://exercism.io/submissions/85c7697232034453baeb130b8982eea3).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
def rand_letters
  ('A'..'Z').to_a[rand(26)]
end

def rand_numbers
  (0..9).to_a[rand(10)]
end

p ((1..2).map { rand_letters } + (1..3).map { rand_numbers }).join
```

---

When you using `map(&:rand_letters)` syntax you send message to each element of the collection. In our case `Fixnum` objects receive message (:rand_letters) and can't respont to that message because it is not defined in the class `Fixnum`

In my example messages `:rand_letters` and `:rand_numbers` are not passed to `Fixnum` instance, but to `self`, where thery are defined.

Here how you can use it within a class:

```
class A
  def rand_letters
    ('A'..'Z').to_a[rand(26)]
  end

  def rand_numbers
    (0..9).to_a[rand(10)]
  end

  def name    
    (1..2).map { rand_letters } + (1..3).map { rand_numbers }.join
  end
end

A.new.name
```