# Implementing &:method with custom methods

Tags: ruby

I've already read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388368/symbolto-proc-with-custom-methods) but I'm having trouble implementing the concepts there.

I'm doing an exercise from exercism.io that has provided tests. The aim of the exercise is to implement an accumulate method that returns the squares of the numbers passed to it. We need to do this without using map/inject.

That was no problem but one of the tests is as follows:

```
  def test_accumulate_upcases
    result = %w(hello world).accumulate(&:upcase)
    assert_equal %w(HELLO WORLD), result
  end
```

I have the following class

```
class Array

  def accumulate
    squares = []
    self.each { |x| squares << x**2 unless x.is_a? String }

    squares
  end

  def upcase
    upcase = []
    self.each { |word| word.upcase }

    upcase
  end
end
```

But I don't fully understand the concept being tested. How to I get `accumulate` to call methods that are passed to it as arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are expected to extend `Array` class with new method `accumulate` which will accumulate the results of invoking a given `proc` on each element of the array.

One implementation can be like this:

```
class Array
    def accumulate(&block) 
        self.collect { |i| block.yield(i) }
    end
end

p result = %w(hello world).accumulate(&:upcase)  # Prints ["HELLO", "WORLD"]
p result = %w(hello world).accumulate { |b| b.upcase } # Prints ["HELLO", "WORLD"]
```

Please note that `%w(HELLO WORLD)` is same as array `["HELLO", "WORLD"]`

There is a very good explanation of what is the use of `&` operator in [this article](http://ablogaboutcode.com/2012/01/04/the-ampersand-operator-in-ruby/) - please read the section on **The Unary &**

Comment: This works perfectly! Although I used `each` instead of `collect` because the exercise wants us to accumulate results manually. And thank you for the link as well!

Comment: You can just pass the block, i.e. `collect(&block)`

Answer (score 0):

`accumulate` method is expecting to receive a name of the method as `Symbol`.

```
def accumulate meth = nil
  result = []
  case 
  when meth.nil?
    self.each { |e| result << e.public_send meth }
  when block_given?
    self.each { |e| result << yield e }
  else
    fail 'This method expects either block or method name'
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. If you don't mind though, what's `public_send`

Comment: Thanks @SergioTulentsev - that's useful information to know!