# calling slice! with map / symbol_to_proc syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails app with something like this:

```
[{name: 'joe'}, {name:'jane', sort: true, suppress: false}].map {|i| i.slice!(:sort, :suppress) }
```

and would like to use something like  `map(&:slice ... )` but not sure if this can be done. I see this question [Symbol#to_proc with custom methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388368/symbolto-proc-with-custom-methods) but is 5 years old and think that this must be supported esp in Rails. How would I do this?

currently doing

```
[{name: 'joe'}, {name:'jane', sort: true, suppress: false}].map {|i| i.slice!(:sort, :suppress) }
```

Comment: When you give an example please show the desired result (as a Ruby object). It's also helpful to assign variables to all inputs (e.g., `arr = [{name: 'joe'}, ... ]`) so those variables can be referenced in answers and comments without having to define them. You also need to define the object `some`.

Comment: A few others and I had a bit of fun with this a while back feel free to take a look at [This SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34579603/chaining-to-proc-on-symbol) for ideas.

Comment: thx @CarySwoveland slice! is in place so doesn't need and apologize for the some method name; hopefully understandable from context. I liked your book!

Comment: The book, I'm afraid, is in its early stages, and the probablility it will be completed is less than 1.0, but thanks anyway. I'm trying to negotiate a movie deal but no luck to date. Note while the method you refer to mutates the elements of the array it creates a new array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know that is the simplest way to do it without monkey patching as indicated in the link you gave. You really aren't saving much time by using a more compact format. If you want to compact it more, you can move the map into it's own method. then do something like

```
def map_slice!(arr, *fields)
  arr.map {|i| i.slice!(*fields) }
end

map_slice!(arr, :sort, :suppress)

# Not much shorter than just using below
# Which is why it probably wasn't implemented.
arr.map {|i| i.slice!(:sort, :suppress) }
```

Comment: thx - y - I feel like I google this every 6 months or a year

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not possible without monkey patching. Anyway if you have strong desire, you could patch the Symbol class.

```
class Symbol
  def with(*args, &block)
    ->(caller, *rest) { caller.send(self, *rest, *args, &block) }
  end
end
```

and then you could use it like:

```
[{name: 'joe'}, {name:'jane', sort: true, suppress: false}].map(&:slice.with(:name, :suppress))
```